# Where do I use Pretender to enable Ember Qunit integration tests with rails-csrf?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-qunit

We are using [rails-csrf](https://github.com/abuiles/rails-csrf) in our ember-cli app. The README on rails-csrf [says](https://github.com/abuiles/rails-csrf#working-with-integration-tests):

> Be sure to mock out the call to the csrf server endpoint. Otherwise your tests will fail with
>
> `"error while processing route: [route]"`
>
> messages in the browser console. For example:

```
server = new Pretender(function() {
  this.get('/csrf', function(request) {
    return [200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      JSON.stringify({
        "authenticity_token": "token"
      })
    ];
  });
});
```

I understand the problem here (our integration tests are indeed showing this error) and I understand how [Pretender](https://github.com/trek/pretender) solves it. I've got Pretender installed via [ember-cli-pretender](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-pretender).

What I don't understand is how to make sure this code snippet - configuration for a Pretender mock - is working. I have it installed in the `setup` block of the integration test module, and it gets called, but the error is still present and the tests still aren't passing.

Here's the current non-working state:

```
module('Integration test', {
  setup: function() {
    App = startApp();

    var server = new Pretender(function() {
      this.get('/our/api/for/csrf', function(request) {
        return [200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
          JSON.stringify({
            "authenticity_token": "token" 
            // I've also tried putting a real token from the server here instead of "token"
          })
        ];
      });
    });
  },
  teardown: function() {
    Ember.run(App, App.destroy);
  }
});
```

The mock is getting called, but whatever it's returning is apparently not enough for rails-csrf. It looks like the `beforeModel` call in the application route is returning a promise; it's not clear if that's expected and being resolved.

(This question is superficially similar to [this older one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17177218/306084), but the available tools for handling this in Ember have changed significantly.)

Comment: Instantiating Pretender inside `setup` should be working, that is a correct place to do it. Look for something else that might be off.

Comment: @givanse that's good to know! I fixed the actual URL we're sending the CSRF request to, as well. I wonder if that `server` var I'm assigning the Pretender instance to is getting referenced anywhere? Or does that matter?

Comment: I've verified that the Pretender mock is getting called. I guess it's not returning what it needs to return?

Comment: Can you setup a jsbin?

Comment: I've tried setting up a jsbin a few times, but the thicket of errors I've been fighting through (getting the environment set up, basically) just to get to the error I have in my app is horrific. I'll take another stab at it, but I'm not optimistic, especially getting rails-csrf into the mix.

Comment: I'm also taking a spike into updating versions - we're on ember-cli 0.1.12 and ember 1.8.1, so jumping to 0.1.15 and 1.10.x respectively might be worth trying to see if it clears up something obscure.

Comment: So far the update to ember 1.10.x is looking promising; at the very least I'm getting a different error now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated our app from ember-cli 0.1.12 and ember 1.8.1 to ember-cli 0.2.0 and ember 1.10.0. *I also updated Pretender to 0.6.0 (the ember-cli-pretender package installed 0.1.0).* This didn't solve anything by itself, but it did lead to a telling change in how the integration test failed. Now, Pretender was intercepting data requests and returning an error because I hadn't defined handlers for them.

> Error: Pretender intercepted GET /our/api/data/:id but no handler was defined for this type of request

So the issue was no longer Ember but my configuration of Pretender. Once I mocked data requests to the API, we were off and running.

tl;dr make sure you have the latest version of Pretender.